# Best model to measure exponential growth

Tags: exponential-function, regression

I'm just trying to measure the growth rate of an exponential curve. I've tried

$y = e^{ax} + b$

where $a$ would be the "how fast the curve grows".

Is this the right fit? Or are there better models for what I want to measure?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $y=be^{ax}$ might be a common way to start so its logarithm $\log(y)=\log(b)+ a \log(x)$ was linear

Comment: I thought about that too, but in this case, growth would depend on A and B, right? What I wanted to achieve was a single variable that would quantify how fast it has grown.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "growth".  Suppose you you want find the factor by which $y$ grows when $x$ increases to $x+t$.  In my formulation this is $\dfrac{be^{a(x+t)}}{be^{ax}} = e^{at}$ so is unaffected by $b$.

Comment: Solved.Thanks!!